# Does the Google+ Hangouts API support filling app fields on the runtime?

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

I am trying to build a app using the hangout API, *[starter app](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-hangout-samples/downloads/list)*.
Does the Hangouts API have support for data fields to be added on runtime?

For example,

```
a. If we need to add team members to our app
b. Or when we do 'Create Application' (https://appengine.google.com/)
c. When we enter AppEngine app ID to Gadget URL (https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=plusHangouts)
```

Can we do the above using Python code and using the API (if there are any)?

Answer (score 3):

As documented in *[Google APIs Console Help](http://code.google.com/apis/console-help/)* we don't let people programmatically register data into the APIs console.

Don't forget that that the current restrictions are because we are in a developer preview.